# Call function on scroll once in React-Native

Tags: android, ios, animation, react-native, scrollview

I'm building an app, where I have a realizable header called `<SearchBar />` which has prop `isCollaped` (value can be true or false) which opens and closes the container, and a `<ScrollView />` (Screenshot below, sorry for not having text in English).
Screenshots of an app:

[Case when `isCollaped == false`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ryBB.png)

[Case when `isCollaped == true`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0addT.png)

I want to collapse the `<SearchBar />` when starting to scroll the `<ScrollView />` so I am setting the value of `isCollaped` to true, and it works, but because of `<ScrollView />` calling `onScroll` every 200ms, and Scrolling animation not stopping after releasing a finger, when I try to open the `<SearchBar />` again by pressing on it, and if the scroll animation is still active, I'm getting a really buggy animation that collapses the `<SearchBar />` again.

This part of the code resizes the SearchBar when pressing on it:

```
collapseSearchBar = () => {
   this.setState({
      searchBarCollapsed: !this.state.searchBarCollapsed,
   });
};
```

This is the `<SearchBar/>`:

```
<SearchBar
   isCollapsed={this.state.searchBarCollapsed}
   onCollapse={this.collapseSearchBar}
   onSearch={this.search}
/>
```

This is the code for `<ScrollView />`:

```
<ListView
      ref='mainScrollView'
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={(rowData) => {
          return this._renderRow(rowData, this.props.navigation);
      }}
      onScroll={() => {
        if (!this.state.searchBarCollapsed) {
          this.setState({
            searchBarCollapsed: true
          });
        }
      }}
/>
```

My question is: How can I make a `<ScrollView />` call `onScroll` just once, when user swipes it, and not all the time (every 200ms, for about 3 seconds after the animation starts), while the animation is active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`scrollEventThrottle`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#scrolleventthrottle) prop to set how often the `scroll` event will fire.

> **scrollEventThrottle**
>
> This controls how often the scroll event will be fired while scrolling
>   (as a time interval in ms). A lower number yields better accuracy for
>   code that is tracking the scroll position, but can lead to scroll
>   performance problems due to the volume of information being send over
>   the bridge. You will not notice a difference between values set
>   between 1-16 as the JS run loop is synced to the screen refresh rate.
>   If you do not need precise scroll position tracking, set this value
>   higher to limit the information being sent across the bridge. The
>   default value is zero, which results in the scroll event being sent
>   only once each time the view is scrolled.

But I don't think this would solve your problem. What you can do to set a second state value (*something like `isAnimating`*) and check that before animating the header. After the animation ends you can set that back to false.

**Example**

```
<ListView
      ref='mainScrollView'
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={(rowData) => {
          return this._renderRow(rowData, this.props.navigation);
      }}
      onScroll={() => {
        if (!this.state.searchBarCollapsed) {
          this.setState({
            searchBarCollapsed: true,
            isAnimating: true
          });
        }
      }}
/>
```

---

```
collapseSearchBar = () => {
   this.interval = setInterval(() => {
     if (this.state.isAnimating === false) {
       this.setState({
         searchBarCollapsed: !this.state.searchBarCollapsed,
         isAnimating: true
       });
       clearInterval(this.interval);
       this.interval = null;
     }
   }, 100)
};
```

Comment: As you have said `scrollEventThrottle` didn't work for me, so I've tried the second approach too, but it doesn't seem to work. It just lets me to collapse `<SearchBar />` once and then does nothing, I guess it's because of not having a line of code where the `isAnimating` value is set to `false`. Maybe you could suggest some changes to your code, so that the animation works all the time.

Comment: @MishoTektumanidze I can't suggest anything else because I have no idea how you animate your component. Mine was just a suggestion on how to achieve the desired behavior. You need to implement it somehow on your code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to animate a view on scroll up once and on scroll down once. Basically, it like showing the view when scroll down and hiding it when scroll up. Since function was being called multiple time while scrolling it was giving a flickering effect in the view. So I created a state 'scrollDown).

```
const [scrollDown, setScrollDown] = useState(true)
```

Initially scrollDown will be true in my case indicating user will scroll down at first. And animation will execute because it true and it will also update itself to false so next time animation will not executed. Of course, !scrollDown will give true but those code will not execute because those are for scroll up. So, once user scroll up, then scrollDown value will update and same logic will follow.

```
const _toogleNavigationBtn = (event) => {
    const currentOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;

    if(scrollDown)
        if(currentOffset > offset && offset > 0 ){
                setScrollDown(prevState => !prevState)
                Animated.timing(navigationBtnY,{
                        toValue: 50,
                        duration: 700,
                        easing: Easing.out(Easing.exp)
                    }).start();
        }

    const contentSize = parseInt(event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height)
    const scrolledSize = parseInt(currentOffset + event.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.height)
    if(!scrollDown)
        if(offset === 0 || currentOffset < offset || contentSize == scrolledSize){
            setScrollDown(prevState => !prevState)
            Animated.timing(navigationBtnY,{
                        toValue: 0,
                        duration: 700,
                        easing: Easing.out(Easing.exp)
                    }).start();
        }


    setOffset(prevState => currentOffset)
}
```